# Lambda function issue: "Unable to import module 'embedding_search_handler': attempted relative import beyond top-level package",

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an Elasticsearch instance up and I am using API Gateway + Lambda to set up a little backend. The ES contains embeddings of some Word Docs that I generated for a "chat with your docs" LLM thing.

This is embedding_search_handler.py:

```
import os
import json
import requests
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
from decouple import config
import sys
sys.path.append('./')

# Elasticsearch setup
host = 'https://myhost.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com'
region = 'us-east-1'

# Retrieve keys from the .env file using python-decouple
ACCESS_KEY = config('ACCESS_KEY')
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')
OPENAI_API_KEY = config('OPENAI_API_KEY')

awsauth = AWS4Auth(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY, region, 'es')

es = Elasticsearch(
    hosts=[{'host': host, 'port': 443}],
    http_auth=awsauth,
    use_ssl=True,
    verify_certs=True,
    connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection
)

def query_elasticsearch(embedding):
    try:
        body = {
            "size": 5,
            "query": {
                "script_score": {
                    "query": {"match_all": {}},
                    "script": {
                        "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, 'embedding_vector') + 1.0",
                        "params": {"query_vector": embedding}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        response = es.search(index="document_embeddings", body=body)
        return response['hits']['hits']
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error querying Elasticsearch: {e}")
        return []

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    query_text = event['query']
    query_embedding = convert_query_to_embedding(query_text)
    if not query_embedding:
        return {
            "statusCode": 500,
            "body": json.dumps({"error": "Failed to get embedding for query"})
        }
    
    results = query_elasticsearch(query_embedding)
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps(results)
    }

def convert_query_to_embedding(query):
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {OPENAI_API_KEY}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    
    try:
        response = requests.post(
            "https://api.openai.com/v1/embed",
            headers=headers,
            json={
                "model": "text-embedding-ada-002",
                "data": [query]
            }
        )
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raises a HTTPError if the HTTP request returned an unsuccessful status code
        
        data = response.json()
        embedding = data['data'][0]['embedding']
        return embedding
    except requests.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error calling OpenAI API: {e}")
        return None
```

When I try to run this test inside Lambda:

```
{
  "query": "what is this?"
}
```

I get this error:

```
START RequestId: 5cdd60ba-562b-4cb5-a5f9-b02bbbb26a97 Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'embedding_search_handler': attempted relative import beyond top-level package
Traceback (most recent call last):END RequestId: 5cdd60ba-562b-4cb5-a5f9-b02bbbb26a97
REPORT RequestId: 5cdd60ba-562b-4cb5-a5f9-b02bbbb26a97  Duration: 1.10 ms   Billed Duration: 2 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 50 MB
```

This is what my directory looks like:
[image]

When I am inside the dir "lambda_package" and run `zip -r ../lambda_package.zip`, it also appears to zip correctly. This is the screenshot from zipping and unzipping the contents:
[image]

When I go to "Edit runtime settings", my Handler is set to "embedding_search_handler.lambda_handler"

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You might be missing ```__init__.py``` at your root level and any other levels where your imported packages are located to let **python** know where the hierarchy is rooted and where to get packages from.

Comment: I put an empty __init__.py in the root at your suggestion -- unfortunately I still am getting the same error

Comment: Note that your ```PYTHONPATH``` variable should include the path where your ```__init__.py``` and your project root are located and where ```embedding_search_handler.py``` is located, thus if interpreter doesn't know this path is part of ```PYTHONPATH```, it won't find it. So you might need to verify you're using the right **Python** inrepreter with valid ```PYTHONPATH```.

Comment: Also, given your interpreter is **Python3**, you may try using ```import .embedding_search_handler``` at the same location (with **dot** prior to the package name.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to create a lambda layer containing the library or build the lambda function from an ECR image with a requirements.txt and a dockerfile.